How can I reduce a class to something it implements while keeping the most narrow generic definitions?
I have a parent class and a child class in TypeScript, where the child class extends the parent with more specific generic types. I'm trying to create a type utility that extracts the parent class type from the child class, but preserves the exact generic types used in the inheritance, rather than widening them to their constraints.
Here's my code:
class Parent<A extends number, B extends string> { }

class Child<A extends 4, B extends 3, C extends "a", D extends 1>
  extends Parent<D, C> { }

type ToParent<T> = T extends Parent<infer A, infer B> ? Parent<A, B> : never;

type Test = ToParent<Child<4, 3, "a", 1>>

Playground
The problem is that Test resolves to Parent<number, string>, but I want it to be Parent<1, "a">.
I need a type utility that can:

Work with any class that extends Parent
Extract the Parent type with the exact generic arguments used in the extension
Preserve the specific types without widening them to their constraints

The use case is that I want to be able to get the most specific possible Parent<A, B> for any class that extends Parent, regardless of how many additional generic parameters the child class might have.
How can I modify my ToParent type to achieve this?

Empty classes make for poor examples. If you add properties that structurally depend on your type parameters like this then it just works. So is this a [mre] that's too minimal, or just a confusion about how structural typing works? Please [edit] to fix/clarify.

You got it. Thank you

I got what? I'm confused. It doesn't look like you edited or answered my question, so... how do we proceed?

It was an overly minimal example, and you proved it.  My core question remains unanswered, but I can't seem to make a minimal example and I've already moved on.

So then maybe delete the question?

TL;DR
You're checking if T extends Parent when you should be checking T extends Child, since you want to infer type arguments from that class.

Explanation
I believe the problem is with your conditional checking if T extends Parent<infer A, infer B>. While Child<4, 3, "a", 1> does extend from Parent<1, "a">, I believe this breaks the type inference.
My assumption is that Typescript isn't able to narrow down to Parent<1, "a">, but only to Parent<number, string>, because that's as specific as your definition is. You're trying to access the types of the arguments of the Parent your Child extends, but that's not going to be aware of the types of the arguments of the Child, which it sounds like is what you want.
Your ToParent conditional type needs to follow the same logic as your Child class: expect a Child to be passed and infer the last two type arguments, then expect it to extend a Parent with those two arguments reversed.
class Parent<A extends number, B extends string> { }

class Child<A extends number, B extends number, C extends string, D extends number>
extends Parent<D, C> { }

type ToParent<T> = T extends Child<infer A, infer B, infer C, infer D> ? Parent<D, C> : never;

type TestParent = Parent<1, "a">
type TestChild = Child<4, 3, "a", 1>
type Test = ToParent<TestChild>
// type of Test is now: Parent<1, "a">

type Test2 = ToParent<Child<12, 11, "b", 2>>
// type of Test2 is: Parent<2, "b">

As demonstrated above, I believe you can also loosen up your definition of the Child class, depending on your implementation needs, to allow for various Child classes to be instantiated with different type arguments. You can see in the updated playground that the type inference in ToParent still works.
Hope this helps!
Happy typing!
